# Why my latest version Visual Studio 2022 does not contain any project under the solution in the Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

The Solution Explorer cannot display the project I create after I upgrade Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0. Is there any package or component I missed? Pls do not suggest uninstall the Visual Studio 2022, because I have uninstalled and installed it for two times...So I think it should be caused by missing some component or package.

Here is the steps I do:

1.Choose the Template:

[image]

2.Configure my project and additional information, then click the create button to create the solution with project

[image]

[image]

The Result I get:

[image]

And you can see the project exists in my local folder:
[image]

For installation, I just choose the following options and do not change anything:

[image]

For .net core sdk:

[image]

**Note:** Before I upgrade to v17.4.0, it works fine.

I want the project show in the Solution Explorer then I can run the web application

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my end, but I am using version 17.4.0 Preview 3.  It seems really odd though.  Can you right click on the solution in solution explorer and add the project? What happens then?

Comment: Hi @Timothy G., I also right-click the solution and add project, it also will create the project in my local folder but do not display in the solution explorer.

Comment: Hi guys, yesterday evening I tried third time to reinstall the app, and this morning it works!!! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Either a bad install or maybe there was a new update. Either way, glad it's working.

Answer (score 2):

First i checked the SDK I opened CMD and typed.

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

it displayed no sdks.
[image]
Finally, I solved it by moving the x64 directory a level up in the PATH environment variable and now everything works.
you can check and try.