# Cannot create new project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Cannot create new project in Visual Studio 2022

The project created but he invisible in the visual studio.
[image]

I tried to uninstall and install the VS.
It's happens on any project type and any framework.

VS Installer configuration:
{
"version": "1.0",
"components": [
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
"Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSODBC.SQL",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MSSQL.CMDLnUtils",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
"Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.SDK",
"Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.2.TargetingPack",
"Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.TSServer",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
"Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.RazorExtension",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IISExpress",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools",
"Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.SSDT",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources",
"Component.Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager",
"Component.Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.WebLivePreview",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web",
"Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.6.0",
"Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.7.0",
"Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp",
"Microsoft.ComponentGroup.ClickOnce.Publish",
"Microsoft.NetCore.Component.DevelopmentTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools",
"Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Web",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web",
"Microsoft.Net.Component.4.8.TargetingPack",
"Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.4.8.DeveloperTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet45",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AspNet",
"Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.Snapshot",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web.CloudTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliTrace.FrontEnd",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.LiveUnitTesting",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
"Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.LiveShare.2022",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WslDebugging",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling",
"microsoft.net.runtime.mono.tooling.net6",
"microsoft.net.sdk.emscripten.net6",
"wasm.tools.net6",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DotNetModelBuilder",
"Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop"
]
}

Comment: What type of project are you trying to create? And can you share with us your VS Installer configuration?

Comment: This seems very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the They uninstalled and reinstalled the application (3 times...) and it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved that issue by uninstall all the installed .net core preview SDKs in my pc.