# Visual Studio 2022 dosen't see files in project when I create ASP.Net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have problem with my Visual. When I tried to create ASP.NET project, visual studio doesn't see any files in project. I see only No solution(0) . I create project in the same way like in this topic : [Why my latest version Visual Studio 2022 does not contain any project under the solution in the Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the/74674762#74674762)

I Tried to reinstall visual about 6 times. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: did you test  right click the project and click reload project?

Comment: Yes, but it dosen't help.

Comment: There use to be two methods for database 1) Code First 2) Database first.  The second database first has been eliminated and you have to start with c# classes.

Comment: @jdweng the question is not about databases, as far I can see

Comment: This is one of the rare circumstances where a screenshot might indeed be useful

Comment: @KlausGütter : The files the OP is referring to is a database if you look at the link the OP already provided.   The OP also is using asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to use a version project framework that you don't installed yet.

it's seems to be that the solution is format and reinstall windows, easy ;)

Comment: Yes I installed .NET 6 and 7 and I Have still this problem.

Comment: ok, update the last visual studio patch, works for other. But in the output windows, what is the error?

Comment: I have the latest version. Outpout windows shows no error

Comment: I had the same problem and I fixed it by modifying the VS setup.

When i installed it i checked the “Web Development ASP.NET and web” as i used to do in Visual Studio 2019, but it seems like in this version this only installs Core, so i couldn’t add any views or controllers, nor create a new MVC5 .NET project.

I added the selections that i’m showing in the next screenshot and now it’s working fine.
Hope it helps if you wanna try VS 2022 again.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs-2022-add-view-to-mvc-project-doesnt-work/1577500

Comment: Unfortunetly, link with ss isn't avaliable :/

Comment: I tried install VS19. I have the same problem. I don't have idea how to repair this problem

Comment: have you tried another version of the framework? Only fail on this version?

Comment: On this two I tried on 6 and 7.

Comment: do you watch this?: https://blog.ndepend.com/visual-studio-2022-messing-up-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: I just format my widnows, because after update do 11 I had some strange problems. Now it's working :)

Comment: @patrykk1797 Do you mean that you have solved the question?

Comment: @patrykk1797 If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)