# Visual Studio 2022 Not Opening Projects

Tags: .net, installation, visual-studio-2022

I have just downloaded Visual Studio 2022 community and am having some problems creating a project.

When I create a new project of any type, console, asp.net core etc., all I get is an empty solution. The project does not show in the solution. The build option are not available either.

[blank solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMyL6.jpg)

Then, when I go to the project folder and try to open the .csproj file, I get the following error:
[sdk error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihu6F.jpg)

When I list the sdks:

[image]

I have the sdk.net 6 package installed:

[sdks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y0Bb.jpg)

[sdk-manifests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uSVX.jpg)

Also, I have uninstalled 2022, installed 2019 community and am having the same problem.

Any direction you can give me is much appreciated

Comment: How did you create those projects? Did you install the correct workloads in VS?

Comment: I used the VS projects templates. I don't see that I missed a workload in the installation. I'm curious if this has something to do with the environment variables.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times with no clear solution. One example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the The only solution I remember a user finding was reinstalling Visual Studio multiple times until it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I manually downloaded the x86 .Net 6 sdk, and now the .Net 6 sdk shows under dotnet --list-sdks. And now visual studio works correctly.